# Converting bits to kilobits+ and converting bytes to kilobytes+? What is the correct convention 1000, 1024 or both?

Tags: calculus, binary

I am trying to understand how to convert bits larger types of bits, and bytes to larger types of bytes and vice versa but I've come across numerous methods and they conflict.

Is the following correct?

"To convert from bits to kilobits and beyond you are dividing by 1000^n. to convert from larger bits, for instance kilobyte you are multiplying by 1000^n.

In contrast when you are converting bytes upwards you are dividing by 1024^n and when you are converting down to bytes your multiplying by 1024^n.

finally to convert between bytes to bits your dividing by 8 and vice versa your multiplying?"

Is the above correct or should you just use one convention. i.e. either 1000 or 1024?

Comment: A computing question rather than a mathematics question.

Comment: This is not mathematics but computer conventions (and marketing).  Some people call 1024 bytes a kilobyte , while others call 1000 bytes a *kilobyte* and 1024 bytes a *kibibyte*, and you should check what they mean.  You as an individual might try to be self-consistent, as it makes explaining yourself easier

Comment: Which  is correct  depends entirely on the context. The context determines the convention.

Answer (score 1):

Kilo = 1,000. Mega = 10^6. Giga = 10^9. Tera = 10^12. In CS, we maybe use KiBi = 1,024, MeBi = 1,024^2, GiBi = 1,024^3 etc.

For RAM sizes, usually base-1024 numbers are used, often with the wrong unit name. Practically everything else uses base-1,000 numbers.